# Create window inside another window?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark

I have a dataframe like this

```
+----+-----+
|name|value|
+----+-----+
|   A|    7|
|   A|    5|
|   A|    1|
|   A|    1|
|   A|    1|
|   A|    6|
|   A|    1|
|   A|    1|
|   A|    1|
|   B|    2|
|   B|    1|
+----+-----+
```

and I wanna convert it to a dataframe with these values:

```
+----+-----+
|name|value|
+----+-----+
|   A|    7|
|   A|    5|
|   A|    5|
|   A|    5|
|   A|    5|
|   A|    6|
|   A|    6|
|   A|    6|
|   A|    6|
|   B|    2|
|   B|    2|
+----+-----+
```

Indeed I want to make a window by a partition over the `name` field, and then make a window (or something like that?) inside it which starts from the `value` of the current row and group data for following rows until a value other than one will appear.

How can I do that?

Comment: How should be the ordering of  'value' column.

Comment: @Manish `1` values are optional and can be anything else, but they must in the same order as the original dataframe is. I mean finally after `7`, there must be four `7`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the idea from @Manish on comments, I changed `1` values to `null` and added an `order` column which uniquely indicates the order of rows.

```
+----+-----+-----+
|name|order|value|
+----+-----+-----+
|   A|    1|    7|
|   A|    2|    5|
|   A|    3| null|
|   A|    4| null|
|   A|    5| null|
|   A|    6|    6|
|   A|    7| null|
|   A|    8| null|
|   A|    9| null|
|   B|   10|    2|
|   B|   11| null|
+----+-----+-----+
```

Then using `last` method with `ignorenulls` argument, solved the problem.

```
win1 = Window.partitionBy("name").orderBy("order")
s = F.last(d.value, ignorenulls = True).over(win1)

d = d.withColumn(
    'value1',
    F.when(
        d.name == F.lag('name').over(win1),
        s
    ).otherwise(s)
)

d.show()

+----+-----+-----+
|name|order|value|
+----+-----+-----+
|   B|   10|    2|
|   B|   11|    2|
|   A|    1|    7|
|   A|    2|    5|
|   A|    3|    5|
|   A|    4|    5|
|   A|    5|    5|
|   A|    6|    6|
|   A|    7|    6|
|   A|    8|    6|
|   A|    9|    6|
+----+-----+-----+
```